# Getting undefined data when trying to use Graphql query and passing a post Id

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js

I get a post id from some props in Next js and I am trying to pass it to my Graphql part like in the code snippet below

But I get undefined data as a result, and if I manually pass the Id (which is a string) I am able to fetch desired data.

It returns me 400 response

and in VS Code, if I hover of the PostID variable, it shows that it is unused but I am already using this variable inside the gql portion, can somebody help me debug this?

```
const PostID=JSON.stringify(props.id.id);

       const FETCH_POST_QUERY = gql`
       query getPost($postId:String)
        {
            getPost(postId:$PostID){
                body
                createdAt
                id
                username
            }
        }
    
         `
   
        const fetchPost = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY);
        console.log(fetchPost);
```

Comment: are you using apollo ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Apollo Client

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in the variables names in your query:

```
query getPost($postId:String)
        {
            getPost(postId:$postId){
                body
                createdAt
                id
                username
            }
        }
```

If this is not fixing your problem, please share your schema.

Comment: getPost(postId:String!):Post

This is my Query in Type Definition, I also suspected that I am passing something wrong, but when I try to pass value of post (not the variable itself) I get desired result.

Also I made a typo here (stackoverflow) in my code snippet, it should be small case p instead of cap P, I will edit it here also (I don't think so this is the reason of problem)

Comment: please share your schema

Comment: type Post{
    id:String!
    body:String!
    createdAt:String!
    username:String!
    comments:[Comment]! 
    likes:[Like]!
    likeCount:Int!
    commentCount:Int!
}

Comment: where are your queries and mutations definitions?

Comment: In my backend portion? Can you kindly explain what exactly are you asking for? Should I share  complete code of my schema?

Comment: You must pass the postID to the `variables` option of `useQuery`: `const fetchPost = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, { variables: { postID } });`, you also need to correct the name of the variables in the query to `postID` or in the variables option : `{ variables: { postId: postID }`